# Pandas OR statement ending in series contains

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df` that has columns `type` and `subtype` and about 100k rows, I'm trying to classify what kind of data `df` contains by checking `type` / `subtype` combinations. While `df` can contain many different combinations there are particular combinations that only appear in certain data types. To check if my objects contains any of these combinations I'm currently doing:

```
typeA = ((df.type == 0) & ((df.subtype == 2) | (df.subtype == 3) | 
         (df.subtype == 5) | (df.subtype == 6))) | 
         ((df.type == 5) & ((df.subtype == 3) | (df.subtype == 4) | (df.subtype == 7) | 
         (df.subtype ==  8)))
A = typeA.sum()
```

Where typeA is a long Series of Falses that might have some Trues, if A > 0 then I know it contained a True. The problem with this scheme is that if the first row of the df produces a True it still has to check everything else. Checking the whole DataFrame is faster then using a for loop with a break, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Aside: while it doesn't address the fundamental issue, you could make this shorter -- and maybe get a bit of a performance boost -- by using `df.subtype.isin({2, 3, 5, 6})`.

Comment: @DSM that is a good point! Neatly you can do this within query :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [**Pandas `crosstab`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(100, 2)), columns=["type", "subtype"])
counts = pd.crosstab(df.type, df.subtype)

print counts.loc[0, [2, 3, 5, 6]].sum() + counts.loc[5, [3, 4, 7, 8]].sum()
```

the result is same as:

```
a = (((df.type == 0) & ((df.subtype == 2) | (df.subtype == 3) | 
         (df.subtype == 5) | (df.subtype == 6))) | 
         ((df.type == 5) & ((df.subtype == 3) | (df.subtype == 4) | (df.subtype == 7) | 
         (df.subtype ==  8))))
a.sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

In pandas 0.13 (soon to be released) you can pass this as a [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), which will use [numexpr](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/), which should be more efficient for your usecase:

```
df.query("((df.type == 0) & ((df.subtype == 2) | (df.subtype == 3) | 
         (df.subtype == 5) | (df.subtype == 6))) | 
         ((df.type == 5) & ((df.subtype == 3) | (df.subtype == 4) | (df.subtype == 7) | 
         (df.subtype ==  8)))")
```

Note: I would probably clean up the indentation to make this more readable (you can also replace df.type with type in most cases:

```
df.query("((type == 0) & ((subtype == 2)"
                        "|(subtype == 3)"
                        "|(subtype == 5)"
                        "|(subtype == 6)))"
        "|((type == 5) & ((subtype == 3)"
                        "|(subtype == 4)"
                        "|(subtype == 7)"
                        "|(subtype ==  8)))")
```

Update: It may be able to do this more efficiently, certainly more concisely, using the "in" syntax:

```
df.query("(type == 0) & (subtype in [2, 3, 5, 6])"
        "|(type == 5) & (subtype in [3, 4, 7, 8])")
```